# Why is custom react-native modal not displaying its contents?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Goal: create a custom modal that display different data based on a "type" prop.

Here is CustomModal component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Modal, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import BodyText from './BodyText';
import TransparentInput from './TransparentInput';
import Button from './Button';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class CustomModal extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rating: null,
            visible: props.visible
        };
    }
    handleSubmit = () => {
        alert('Submitting Changes...');
    };
    renderModal = () => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.props));
        switch (this.props.type) {
            case 'bio':
                return (
                    <Modal visible={this.state.visible} transparent={false} animationType={'fade'}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <BodyText text={'Biography: '} style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }} />

                            <BodyText text={this.props.data} style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />

                            <TransparentInput
                                placeholder={'Enter edited details...'}
                                placeholderColor={'white'}
                                style={{ height: width * 0.4, width: width * 0.6 }}
                            />

                            <Button
                                onPress={() => this.handleSubmit(this.props.type)}
                                type={'primary'}
                                text={'Submit'}
                                fontSize={16}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                );
            case 'username':
                return (
                    <Modal visible={this.state.visible} transparent={false} animationType={'fade'}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                          <BodyText text={'Current username: ' + this.props.data} style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
                          <TransparentInput
                              placeholder={'New username'}
                              placeholderColor={'white'}
                              style={{ height: width * 0.4, width: width * 0.6 }}
                          />
                          <Button
                            onPress={() => this.handleSubmit(this.props.type)}
                              type={'primary'}
                              text={'Submit'}
                              fontSize={16}
                          />
                        </View>
                      </Modal>
                  );
        }
    };

    render () {
        return <View style={styles.container}>{this.renderModal()}</View>;
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        height: '100%'
    }
});
```

Here is modal implementation in parent render():

```
render () {
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.visible === true ? (
          <Components.CustomModal
            visible={this.state.visible}
            data={'Placeholder data'}
            type={this.state.modalType}
          />
        ) : null}
      </View>
   )
}
```

Problem: when this.state.visible is set to true in the parent, a screen at 100% height displays with the red background, but no content shows. The props of the customModal are all correct (visible, type, data) as shown by logging props.

whats wrong with this and how can the modal content be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `CustomModal` component you are setting `this.state.visible` to the value of `props.visible`, but since the only time it gets set is in the constructor, it never gets updated.

So even though `this.props.visible` is changing, `this.state.visible` is not.

I don't believe you gain any value by duplicating the visible boolean in state. Try removing that part of state in the `CustomModal` component, and changing to this in both of your switch cases:

```js
<Modal visible={this.props.visible}
```

To still have the ability to toggle the visibility in the `CustomModal`, I would recommend passing it an update function like this:

```js
<Components.CustomModal
  visible={this.state.visible}
  toggleVisible={() => this.setState(prev => ({visible: !prev.visible}))}
  data={'Placeholder data'}
  type={this.state.modalType}
/>

...

// CustomModal
handleSubmit = () => {
  this.props.toggleVisible();
};
```

Comment: Modal's `visible` prop is set by `CustomModa`l's state because im going to be modifying visibility by the `handleSubmit()` method. and if the `this.state.visible` affects the visibility of the child modals like you say, then why is the red background from the child modal being shown in the first place? your suggestion resulted in the same behavior

Comment: Your container is red, so the part that isn't working is inside the renderModal function. console.log the visible state and see verify its working how you expect

Comment: hmm interesting....after an app reboot, its working the way I expect.. your solution also. super weird.